# Automatic Generation of orm.xml file in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, orm, eclipselink

Is there a way i can automatically generate **orm.xml** file in *Netbeans* even if i can modify it later. Am using **eclipselink JPA 2.1** and it keeps giving me this warning when am building

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor' less than -source '1.7'
Note: Creating non-static metadata factory ...
Note: Found Option : eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory, with value: false
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Found Option : eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory, with value: false
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation.
warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory]'
Note: C:\Users\USER\Documents\NetBeansProjects\payroll\src\dcl\payroll\GUI\Login.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 warning
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is just there to let you know that if you are using an orm.xml to define your mappings, it wasn't found.  If you place one there, you will still get messages letting you know one was found.  This gives a notice in the log to help point where to start looking if something unexpected in your application occurs - such as the wrong orm.xml version is used or one is unexpectedly packaged and picked up, which seems a common issue in development.